# Android Testing Platform

Tags: android, automated-tests

First, I am not asking about Unit Testing.  I am asking about the construction of a testing platform like so many out there that can be found by Googling the topic.

I would like to utilize VirtualBox to build an Android Testing Farm.  So for example, download a copy of the Sumsung Emulator for one of their phones and then build a VM on VirtualBox to run it.

What are some of the considerations that I would need to take into account; also, any best practices would help.

**Edit**

Thank you to Ken Wolf for providing the link in the comments below to Google's Firebase Testing Platform.

To user1050755's comment, thank you for the advice.  I guess the better question is how to automate the running for emulators.  Researching this, it appears [Android Studio has a guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkeyrunner/index.html) (Monekyrunner) to do just this.

If anyone has any other suggestion, please post below.

Comment: you don't want to do that. the emulator can make use of kvm and is terribly slow if you don't. run the emulator instead of virtualbox. Stuff like VMs inside VMs is usually a bad idea [tm].

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/